# Is it possible to create a model table while running the rails application?

Tags: ruby, dynamic, model, ruby-on-rails-4

I am working in a small social media project.

Basically, i have 2 models: User and Posts related to the user.

I want to add the concept of friends. So i want to create a Friends table for each user. Each user will point to a his own friends table, where the friends ids are stocked.

Is it create tables of model friend dynamically ? And how to do it if it is possible?

Thanks!

Comment: This is a super bad idea and you'll almost immediately regret doing this. Why are you so concerned about having independent "friends" tables?

Comment: Well, this is a learning project, i will at most have 10 users. I'm more concerned about learning the technicality of doing different things...

Comment: If you're interested in learning, you should follow convention first, then break the rules only when you have a really good reason. Creating piles and piles of individual tables is always trouble and should be an absolute last resort, when all other options have been exhausted. The whole point of a relational database is to be able to query a particular kind of data in different ways, not to have tiny silos of information that have nothing to do with their peers.

Comment: Well, i understood that it is a bad idea, but i understood also that you have no idea on how to do it! Thanks for the clarification and exposing your point of view

Comment: I know how to do it, which is why I'm not even going to get into the explanation of how and it's an extremely messy and difficult process when using ActiveRecord. If you're that curious, I'd say give it a shot, but you're going to find it's actually quite tricky to get right. Are you going to handle deleting these tables when users are deleted? What happens when you want to add a column to the friends structure, how are you going to write a migration? What happens when you open your SQL client and there's 20,000 tables in there? Will it hang or crash?

Answer (score 2):

This is a very bad idea. Instead you should have one friendships table that will manage relations between all users. You can use has_and_belongs_to_many relation or a join model, for example:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :friendships
  has_many :friends, :through => :friendships
end

class Friendship < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :friend, :class_name => 'User', :foreign_key => 'friend_id'
end
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but let me clarify. There is no model Friends right now, there is only User and Posts. So, the Friend model only exists in my proposed solution. If you think is not a suitable solution, then please explain more how am i going to modelize the friendship relation through User model, and if i have to use new models, what should they contain. Thanks!

Comment: Moreover, i am interested in knowing if such thing is doable with the rails framework (even if it might be a bad idea in this particular case)

Comment: "explain more how am i going to modelize the friendship relation through User model" see the example in my answer, it's all there.

Comment: "even if it might be a bad idea in this particular case" it's not a bad idea just in this case but in every case. It is possible as you can run SQL queries directly but will cause you a lot of pain for no gain.

Comment: But you don't know how to do it though! But anyway thanks for your help and your point of view